Spring MVC pass object from list to post-endpoint
I have a spring-controller with a post-endpoint that receives a WordDto. Another get-endpoint puts a list of WordDtos in the ModelMap and shows a jsp-file. In the jsp-file, I show each entry of the list in a row of a table. Each row has additionally a button, that should call the post-endpoint with the WordDto for that row.
But I don't know, how to pass the WordDto from the row correctly to the post-endpoint.
Endpoints
    @GetMapping("/generate")
    public String generateWords(ModelMap model, @RequestParam(value = "language", defaultValue = "-1", required = false) long language, @RequestParam(value = "amount", defaultValue = "-1", required = false) int amount)
    {
        model.put("language", language);
        model.put("amount", amount);

        LanguageData languageData = languageService.getLanguageData(language);

        model.put("languageName", languageData.getName());
        model.put("words", generationService.generateWords(language, amount));

        return "list-words";
    }

    @PostMapping("word")
    public String saveWord(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request, @Valid WordDto singleWord)
    {
        translationService.saveOrGetWord(singleWord);

        return "redirect:" + request.getHeader("Referer");
    }

jsp-file
<body>
    <%--@elvariable id="languageName" type="java.lang.String"--%>
    <h1>Generated words with '${languageName}'</h1>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Word</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <%--@elvariable id="words" type="java.util.List"--%>
        <c:forEach items="${words}" var="singleWord">
            <tr>
                <td>
                        ${singleWord.word}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form:form method="post" action="word" modelAttribute="singleWord.word">
                        <form:input type="hidden" path="languageId"/>
                        <form:input type="text" path="word"/>
                    </form:form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>

How can I send the WordDto, that I have in a row in the jsp-table, to the /word endpoint?

You should use "singleWord" as modelAttribute name in your JSP, as that is the reference to object which you want to bind to the form, that object will be populated once form is submitted and will be received at your post end point

It is unclear what a problem you have sending an object to the controller?

Exactly. The problem is, that with the described way of passing the object, I get the error, that the object is not in the ModelMap. So I'm searching for a way to pass the object successfully to the controller

I got it working, but only with different approach, that is (in my eyes) not as nice as I originally planned. The new version takes two parameters, instead of the entire object at once.
I adjusted the table to look like this:
        <tbody>
        <%--@elvariable id="words" type="java.util.List"--%>
        <c:forEach items="${words}" var="singleWord" varStatus="status">
            <tr>
                <form:form method="post" action="word">
                    <input type="hidden" name="languageId" value="${singleWord.languageId}"/>
                    <td>
                        <label>
                            <input type="text" name="word" value="${singleWord.word}"/>
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                            <%--TODO: Add button to show translation page for this word (Should also save the word before showing the page, if it is not yet saved)--%>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn-success" value="Save">
                    </td>
                </form:form>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
        </tbody

And the endpoint had to be modified too:
    @PostMapping("word")
    public String saveWord(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam(value = "languageId") long languageId, @RequestParam(value = "word") String word)
    {
        translationService.saveOrGetWord(new WordDto(languageId, word));

        return "redirect:" + request.getHeader("Referer");
    }

